# Fixing an iPhone crash with a run-loop stack trace

Tags: iphone, crash, runloop

I'm using hoptoad to track errors in my iPhone app.

One crash that's happened a number of times (14, to be exact), has this stack trace:

https://gist.github.com/2ce8a88c07fc134a3d9c

I'm not even sure how to start investigating this.  Any clues?  The crash seems to come right out of the main run loop - but no information on what caused it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [symbolicating iPad app crash reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499072/symbolicating-ipad-app-crash-reports)

Comment: This is actually a dupe of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499072/symbolicating-ipad-app-crash-reports) -- not that you'd know that without reading that other bug.  The answer has some detailed analysis that may be helpful.

Comment: I suppose its a dupe depending on the question.  If it's how to investigate the issue in the first place, then yes!

Comment: I guess there's not much that can be gleamed from this stacktrace, then.

Answer (score 0):

WEll, it is sort of a dupe of [symbolicating iPad app crash reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499072/symbolicating-ipad-app-crash-reports).  But not much was gleaned there, either.

It looks like an exception was raised and then the catch & report failed due to some other issues.